# need suggestion for implementing website backend functionality

Tags: performance, optimization, architecture

I will be more generalize in this problem statement.

Problem 1:
I will be writing the web application which makes use of one entity (Place). This entity has number of attributes, some of this attribute value are obtained from various web sources and based on that entity will be build.

Entity: Place
Attributes:
Type: [type of place like hill station, beach etc]
Longitude 
Latitude
Review
Distance Array -- based on distance from other places that are selected by user
StartLocation
EndLocation

Question:
What will be better data structure to store this entity? As it will be having lots of update(sometime in realtime) and read operation

Problem 2:
All attributes of the entity contributes to the importance of the entity. Based on this importance entity selection is done. 
Question:
This selection of entity login can be coded in most of the server side languages. But considering computation efficiency, what will be your suggestions for implementing this websites backend?

Comment: Your question is much too general.  There is no way anyone can recommend a particular data structure for "an entity with attributes".

Comment: @Peter I know question is too general. I will say that entity is a place. I will add some more data